# Python Print to File Not Working

Tags: python, file, text, readfile, fwrite

I am trying to execute this script:

```
text_file = open("/Users/test/Test/test.txt", "r")
f = open('/Users/test/TEST/test2.txt','w')
list1 = text_file.readlines()
for item in list1:
    number=0
    while number < 7:
        string=str(item)+str(number)
        number = number + 1
        f.write(string)
```

The file test.txt contains:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Expected output when I open test2:

```
a0
a1
a2
a3
a4
....(actual writing)
d6
```

Actual output:

```
a
0a
1a
2a
3a
4b
0b
1b
2b
3b
4c
0c
1c
2c
3c
4d0d1d2d3d4
```

Just WHAT is going on?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to strip the `'\n'` from `item`. Use [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) for that.

```
for item in list1:
    for number in xrange(7):
        string = item.rstrip() + str(number)
        f.write(string + '\n')
```

Comment: Your actual output looks like you were using 4, not 7 as your loop limit.

The other problem - not mentioned in this answer, is that the last item in your list does NOT have a line feed. That is why your "d"s all ended up on the same line.